# React: Best way to import icons?

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, icons

What is the best way to import icons?

### OPTION 1: Importing from react svg library like `react-icons`

Oftentimes these libraries export all the icons in a common file `index.ts` and then you end up loading up all X,000 icons when loading 1 in development.
`react-icons` has the `@react-icons/all-files` thing going on, but does this actually fix the issue? It seems like it's still an issue oftentimes...? Open to correction.

Modularizing the module doesn't do anything either right? Doesn't seem like it always works or something...? Even using the default react icon libraries provided by providers ends up with a lot of modules when I use it in my NextJS application oftentimes.

### Option 2: Importing the raw svg itself

I end up copy and pasting every icon I need and I can't use it still because I find I need to delete the `width={24} height={24}` on the svg in order to provide correct styling to it like `className="h-5 w-5"`. If I don't delete the width and height in the svg, the viewbox is skewed since width and height are `20` but the viewbox is `0 0 24 24`. Otherwise I need to reset the viewbox and width and height myself which isn't good DX.

I also don't like how importing the SVG directly makes it a default import and you can never auto-import it by name, and if you import it incorrectly, you wouldn't know and the compiler won't tell you until you run your application and it fails to load the svg...

### Summary:

I'm feeling like either I don't understand some nuance on how to import 1 single svg properly in NextJS (cuz I know this is a common trap everyone falls in, importing all the svgs when they only need one cuz the libraries or NextJS is not optimized for this by default in development mode), OR someone needs to create a new library that is like react-icons that symlinks the icons to other github repos but allows you to import the svgs as raw default imports using `@webpack/svgr` or something... Overall just tired of downloading individual icons every time currently. Need some suggestions.

Edit: I see NextJS has this `optimizePackageImports` since Next 13.4/5 [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/optimizePackageImports). Has anyone tried it with good results showing the module count doesn't go up and it working in development?

Answer (score 0):

In react you can import the SVG like this

```
import { ReactComponent as settingsIcon } from "assets/images/NavBar/Deselected/Settings.svg";
import { ReactComponent as settingsIconSelected } from "assets/images/NavBar/Selected/Settings.svg";
```

and then what you can do is create file  and export all the icon from that file

```
export { settingsIcon, settingsIconSelected };
```

then use it you project wherever you need it. Like this

```
import { settingsIcon, settingsIconSelected } from "./Icons";
```